# Listening to tab key on dijit/form/TextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I am using dojo 1.10.4 and I need to listen to tab key on all my `TextBox`.

Is it possible to detect this specific event?

At the moment I am using `onFocus`, but does not solve my issue as it is being triggered in all case included when user click on the `TextBox`.

https://jsfiddle.net/92uc0tmn/8/

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TextBox, registry) {


  var textarea = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onChange: function() {}
  }, "myarea").startup();


  var textarea2 = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea2",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onChange: function() {}
  }, "myarea2").startup();

  var textarea3 = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea3",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onChange: function() {}
  }, "myarea3").startup();
});
```

Comment: `onKey....` event does not work ? `onKeyPress: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }` worked fine....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/92uc0tmn/14/

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks for your comment, I understand your point but I need specifically get the TAB key when user press it on the TextBox. I have found a solution right now posted below. Could you please provide me your feedback? I am interesting to know if this is the right approach or if any better solution using using TextBox class or dijit.form._TextBoxMixin. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What makes you think that this is not a good approach ?

Comment: Not sure if TextBox internally implement already a similar mechanics so I would rather prefer using TextBox implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue using the following code, basically, I listen to `onKeyPress` for `TAB` key.

Still I am not sure if this approach is the best one.
Any idea is welcome.

https://jsfiddle.net/4grtLtvv/

```
require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/registry", "dojo/keys", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TextBox, registry, keys) {


  var textarea = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onKeyPress: function(evt) {
      if (evt.charOrCode === keys.TAB) {
       console.log('tab!');
      }
    }
  }, "myarea").startup();


  var textarea2 = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea2",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onKeyPress: function(evt) {
      if (evt.charOrCode === keys.TAB) {
       console.log('tab!');
      }
    }
  }, "myarea2").startup();

  var textarea3 = new TextBox({
    name: "myarea3",
    value: "Some value",
    intermediateChanges: true,
    selectOnClick: true,
    onKeyPress: function(evt) {
      if (evt.charOrCode === keys.TAB) {
       console.log('tab!');
      }
    }
  }, "myarea3").startup();
});
```